# Why am I getting an error in remote SQL Server installation?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2019 on remote server using PowerShell.
I got error message on remote server.
Can someone please help in identifying the issue.
I tried to grant privileges "trust for delegation" like below link
https://supportcommunity.milestonesys.com/s/article/error-computer-must-be-trusted-for-delegation-and-the-current-user-account-must-be-conf?language=en_US

But still the same error is occurring.

[Install Script]

```
 Start-Process -FilePath $setupFilePath -NoNewWindow -Wait -ArgumentList "/CONFIGURATIONFILE=$configFilePath"
```

[Configuration]
[OPTIONS]

```
IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS="True"
ACTION="Install"
IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS="True"
SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE="True"
QUIET="True"
FEATURES=SQLENGINE,CONN,IS,BC,SDK,SNAC_SDK
INSTANCENAME="MSSQLSERVER"
AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System"
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
ISSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System"
SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic"
SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System"
SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT="True"
SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Domain\Account"
SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT="4"
SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE="1024"
SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH="64"
SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE="512"
SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH="64"
INSTALLSQLDATADIR="C:\MSSQL"
SQLBACKUPDIR="C:\MSSQL\BACKUP"
SQLUSERDBDIR="C:\MSSQL\DATA"
SQLUSERDBLOGDIR="C:\MSSQL\LOG"
TCPENABLED="1"
SECURITYMODE="SQL"
SAPWD="P@ssw0rd"
SQLMAXMEMORY="4915"
SQLMINMEMORY="4915"
IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms="True"
UpdateEnabled="False"
```

[Error]

```
Exception summary:
The following is an exception stack listing the exceptions in outermost to innermost order
Inner exceptions are being indented

Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.ChainerInfrastructureException
    Message: 
        There was an error generating the XML document.
    HResult : 0x84b10001
        FacilityCode : 1201 (4b1)
        ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
    Data: 
      DisableWatson = true
    Stack: 
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(Object objectToSerialize)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.PublicConfigurationBridge.Calculate()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateSettings(IEnumerable`1 settingIds)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.InputSettingService.CalculateAllSettings(Boolean chainerSettingOnly)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.FinalCalculateSettingsAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.Action.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<ExecuteActionWithRetryHelper>b__0()
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionInvocation.ExecuteActionHelper(ActionWorker workerDelegate)
    Inner exception type: System.InvalidOperationException
        Message: 
                There was an error generating the XML document.
        HResult : 0x80131509
        Stack: 
                at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
                at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
                at Microsoft.SqlServer.Chainer.Infrastructure.DataStoreService.SerializeObject(String rootPath, Object objectToSerialize, Boolean saveToCache)
        Inner exception type: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
            Message: 
                        The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation.
                        
            HResult : 0x80090345
            Stack: 
                        at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
                        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Common.SqlSecureString.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
                        at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteSerializable(IXmlSerializable serializable, String name, String ns, Boolean isNullable, Boolean wrapped)
                        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterSqlEngineSetupPublic.Write7_SqlEngineSetupPublic(String n, String ns, SqlEngineSetupPublic o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
                        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterSqlEngineSetupPublic.Write8_SqlEngineSetupPublic(Object o)
```

Comment: `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`? Virtual accounts have been the default for the various component services since about SQL Server 2008 R2, maybe even earlier. e.g.: `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER` for the database engine. Why would you configure all of the services to run with such a highly privileged account? Consider following the [Install SQL Server using a configuration file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-using-a-configuration-file) instructions to create a new configuration.ini file in case there are other issues.